# Concept of differentiation on an abstract set rather than $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I recently learned about differentiation in higher dimension (i.e. function $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$), and I see that the meaning of derivative was transformed to the linear transformation instead of the notion of slope of the tangent line in single variable calculus.

I wonder whether there is the concept of derivative/ differentiation for of a function $f: X \to Y$ where $X, Y$ are two arbitrary sets (rather than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ )? If there is not, could you please explain why can't we define such a concept ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You cannot define differentiation on arbitrary sets, but you can define it on spaces locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. [manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ at the very very least need topology.

Comment: For Banach spaces there are several notions of differentiability: the most common are Frechet, Gateaux, Hadamard. The last can also be defined for Vector spaces that have certain topological property (locally convexity). Here is nice [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative) article. For geometric objects on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or abstract objects that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, (manifolds) there is a way to extend differentiability to functions defined on such objects by using the derivative on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The definition of the derivative isn't changed to be a linear transformation from the slope of the tangent line because the slope of the tangent line is the linear transformation in the single variable case. It's exactly the same idea, approximating a differentiable function by a linear one at a point.